# Update suggestions on autocomplete textview item click

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I have implemented a Autocomplete textview.I have configured it in such a way that every time i click autocomplete textview i show up the suggestions.Everything is working fine except that the suggestions are not updated after I have selected something from the list.Here is my code:

```
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            HomeActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, array);

    textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTV);
    textView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View arg0) {

            textView.showDropDown();

        }
    });
    textView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

For instance if i have String array like {"a", "abvc", "ajedghed", "b", "bdvhd", "bwgdydg", "c", "cswjwwd"}
And i type b,it shows all relevant suggestions with "b" like "b","bdvhd", "bwgdydg".This works fine but if i select any of the suggestion and again click autocomplete textview it still shows previous result drop down on all b's.

I tried adding notifyDataSetChanged() on item click but no luck.

Comment: Thsi is how AutoComplete is configured.

Comment: Well i m sure m not asking for that much of customisation

Comment: what is your expected behavior ?

Comment: @R.Kirill My expected behavior is what NezSpencer has stated.I want my suggestions to be based on selected text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that when you click a text from the drop down, you want the autoComplete suggestion to change based on the new text you selected. To achieve that, you need to extend the autoCompleteTextView class, then override **replaceText()** then in your onItemSelected, call `textView.replaceText((String)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));`

something like this:

**Step1**: override AutoCompleteTextView

```
public class AutoComplete extends AutoCompleteTextView {

public AutoComplete(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public AutoComplete(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public AutoComplete(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public AutoComplete(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

@Override
protected void replaceText(CharSequence text) {
    super.replaceText(text);
}
```

}

**Step2**: change the autoCompleteTextView inyour xml to use the one to created

```
 <com.example.tester.AutoComplete
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:completionThreshold="1"

/>
```

**Step3** add the replaceText in your code like this:

```
final String [] array={"a", "abvc", "ajedghed", "b", "bdvhd", "bwgdydg", "c", "cswjwwd",
            "ssehdk","chakra"};
    final AutoComplete textView=(AutoComplete) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.showDropDown();
        }
    });
    if (textView!=null)
    textView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,array));

    textView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            textView.replaceText((String)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: You got me right !.Thanks for the nice explanation.Seems like this will work but i tried something else which also worked i.e. setting autocomplete view text to the selected text in Onclicklistener.
               ' textView.setText(((TextView) view).getText());'

Comment: wow yours is much shorter :). I assumed once the selected text is displayed in the textView, setText has already been called, and since the suggestion was not updated, it meant setText() did not work.

Comment: Exactly ,setText is not called even if it should.

Answer (score 1):

Try Doing something like this when the user clicks again , so that the textview does not contain any text and the adapter returns all the items in the list.

```
    if(textView.getText().toString() != null && textView.getText().toString().trim() != "")  {
        textView.setText(null);
    }
```

Comment: this will not return the expected set of suggestions,I want my suggestions to be based on the selected text.In this case it will show suggestions corresponding to empty view.

Comment: It is work perfectly when you need to popup whole suggestions.